# Android activity border that can not be removed?

Tags: android, android-activity, margin

So I have this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:id="@+id/mainParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bgdark"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:src="@drawable/myheader_250x60" 
    />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mainListview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Note** I have now edited this post. I was using a grey background image, so I thought that was what was visible to right/left of header image.See below for an image showing the problem.

However, moving the background to the listview did not solve the problem. Hence it would seem it is the imageview that somehow has a left/right border in grey. As i have set width to "match_parent" it should have taken he maximum width.

[image]

The problem is that to the top/right of header there's a grey pixel border? which I would like to remove if possible.

Comment: provide ScreenShot - it will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [scaleType attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType) for your ImageView.

Anothrer way - replace

```
android:src="@drawable/myheader_250x60"
```

for

```
android:background="@drawable/myheader_250x60"
```

Comment: yes, but background property scale image. You need to understand that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using fill_parent instead of match_parent except in listView height . Use wrap_content in listView height

Answer (score 1):

set this scletype property

```
android:scaleType=fitXY
```

and set image to imageview like this

```
android:background="@drawable/myheader_250x60"
```